# Can a handler constantly run in android background?

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, handler, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an android apps that constantly getting the bluetooth le rssi

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                } else {
                    mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                }
            }
        }, 10000);
    }
}
```

In this 10 seconds, i will constantly get the `onScanResult` information. But I don't want this handler stop after 10 seconds. I want it run forever as a background service. Any teacher can help me? thx. Should I use thread, asynctask, looper, or something. I don't know. I just don't want this handler stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Service. Create your own service that extends Service class. In onStartCommand method you should init the scan process and put the periodic alarm.

Hope it helps you!!